# ScheduledExecutorService performance

Tags: java, performance, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a list of objects whose maximum size is 5000. When an object has not been updated for a type specific amount of time like 5, 10 or 100 seconds, it will be deleted from the list.

What is the best or preferred option to handle such a situation?

- Using a scheduled task for each object update. Cancelling old one and reset the new one.
- Or using one scheduled task with fixed delay say 500 ms. Checking the old objects via time comparison...
- or something else.

What do you recommend?

Comment: Could you get the objects themselves to declare that they have expired and then have a listener service dealing with them?

Comment: Search for 'java TimedList' in google.

Comment: It really depends on if you need to perform any action when removing things from the list. If it's a simple remove, you can just use a single thread. If you need to do some work, a pool of threads would be preferable.

Comment: Actually i wrote the question from my friend's account by mistake. I logged out the account. There are types of objects that require different time of expiration such as 5, 10, or 100. Also some further actions are required after expiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use [Google's Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), you should give the [`Cache`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) class a try.

For example, you could have one cache for each type of object:

```
LoadingCache<String, ObjectOfType1> type1Cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(5000)
   .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
   .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<String, ObjectOfType1>() {
         public Graph load(String key) throws AnyException {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

And for `Type2`:

```
LoadingCache<String, ObjectOfType2> type2Cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(5000)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
   .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<String, ObjectOfType2>() {
         public Graph load(String key) throws AnyException {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

Then, you could just use a cache as if it were a `Map`:

```
ObjectOfType1 o1 = type1Cache.get("1");
ObjectOfType2 o2 = type2Cache.get("2");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually using an implementation which uses a `Map<Object, Long>` for storing the expiration times of each element, and a `java.util.Timer` to run every *n* seconds, removing every expired element.

I can't really say it's the *best* implementation, since I only use it for a few hundred simple elements (i.e. not complex objects).